# Custom field sem valor aparece em consulta meta_key no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Ao criar qualquer Custom Field com o plugin ACF, mesmo que eu não adicione qualquer valor a ela em um post, ao fazer uma consulta via meta_key esses posts que não possuem valor são exibidos.

Por exemplo, eu crio um post e numa meta_key eu adiciono uma data de expiração. Se ao comparar essa data e ela for menor que a data atual, ele automaticamente expira. Acontece que os posts que eu não adiciono data de expiração, também expiram, pois eles surgem na consulta por meta_key com valor zerado.

O que desejo é que essa meta_key sem valor não faça parte da consulta. É possível?

Comment: `ao fazer uma consulta via meta_key`, que consulta é essa? Tem código?

Comment: eu não entendi a sua pergunta, mas me ocorreu este plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-expirator/  será que te ajuda?